# gvim to custom highlight group in .vimrc not working

Tags: unix, vim

vim version 6.3

Trying to create a new highlight group to highlight tabs and trailing spaces. I only have these settings in .vimrc.

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight UnwanttedTab ctermbg=red guibg=darkred
match UnwanttedTab /\t/
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight TrailSpace guibg=red ctermbg=darkred
match TrailSpace / \+$/ 
colorscheme torte
```

But when launching vim, I got error like this:

```
line    1:
E216: No such group or event: ColorScheme * highlight UnwanttedTab ctermbg=red guibg=darkred
line    2:
E28: No such highlight group name: UnwanttedTab /\t/
line    3:
E216: No such group or event: ColorScheme * highlight TrailSpace guibg=red ctermbg=darkred
line    4:
E28: No such highlight group name: TrailSpace / \+$/
```

I was following this [guide](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) and using autocmd to prevent my highlight settings to be cleared. But still can't get to work. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: take a look at this tutorial http://vimcasts.org/episodes/show-invisibles/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `match` commands reference custom highlight group names that aren't defined yet. Those group names must be defined using e.g. `highlight UnwanttedTab ...` **before** you use them with `match`. The `autocmds` will only define the highlight group names using `highlight` **after** you've loaded any colorscheme.

This is a way to setup the highlight groups, first defining syntax highlighting with group names, then providing a match for those group names:

```
highlight UnwanttedTab ctermbg=red guibg=darkred
highlight TrailSpace guibg=red ctermbg=darkred
match UnwanttedTab /\t/
match TrailSpace / \+$/
```

The `autocmd` recommendation from the article is intended to prevent any colorschemes that you might load from clearing your custom highlight groups with `:highlight clear`.

Try combining the commands above with the `autocmd`, in your `.vimrc`:

```
highlight UnwanttedTab ctermbg=red guibg=darkred
highlight TrailSpace guibg=red ctermbg=darkred
match UnwanttedTab /\t/
match TrailSpace / \+$/ 

autocmd ColorScheme * highlight UnwanttedTab ctermbg=red guibg=darkred
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight TrailSpace guibg=red ctermbg=darkred

colorscheme torte
```

Comment: tried your solution, but still getting same error message. What could be wrong?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

What the heck are you doing with Vim version 6.3, released in 2004?!

The `ColorScheme` event was only introduced two years later with Vim 7.0, or about six years ago.

Switch to a newer Vim version; then you can also use one of the ready-made plugins for highlighting trailing whitespace, e.g. my [ShowTrailingWhitespace](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966) plugin.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the out dated version not supporting ColorScheme. thanks!